# How do I get the main type and subtype of a Generic Object in dart, For ex Type1<Type2>, I just want the Type1 separatly and Type2 separatly

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the main type and subtype of a generic type in Flutter.
So for example if I have `List<int>`, I want the `List` and `int` both separately. If I do  `<int>[1,2,3].runtimeType` , it gives me `List<int>`. But what if I am only intrested in List or int portion of that information.

I am creating a type compartor for sorting my data

```
int typeSortHelper(Type type1, Type type2){
  if(type1 == type2){
    return 0;
  }

  if(type2 is List){
    type2 = List;
  }

  switch(type1){
    case int: return 1;
    case double:{
      int r;
      if(type2 == int){
        r= -1;
      }else{
        r= 1;
      }
      return r;
    }
    case String:{
      int r;
      if(type2 == int || type2 == double){
        r= -1;
      }else{
        r= 1;
      }
      return r;
    }
    case List:{
      int r;
      if(type2 == int || type2 == double || type2 == String){
        r= -1;
      }else{
        r= 1;
      }
      return r;
    }
    case Map:{
      int r;
      if(type2 == int || type2 == double || type2 == String || type2 == List){
        r= -1;
      }else{
        r= 1;
      }
      return r;
    }
  }

}
```

So when I do a call like this:

```
r1 = typeSortHelper([1,2,3].runtimeType, 2.runtimeType);
```

Its should give me -1, rather it gives me null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can not yet do that.

So your implementation as for 2019 (Dart 2.5) would look like:

```
switch(smth.runtimeType){
  case int: return processInt(smth);
  case Uint8List: return process Uint8List(smth):
  default: if(smth is Map<String, dynamic>){
    processMapStringDynamic(smth);  
  } else if(smth is List<int>){
    processListInt(smth);
  } else throw('unimplemented for ${smth.runtimeType}');
}
```